# Deriving equations for acceleration (homework)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I do not have never studied any physics.

I am asked to find a differential equation for acceleration from the sky diver problem.

```
dv/dt = m - kv/m
```

I differentiate both sides

I think that v = at (acceleration * t) and therefore v'=a v''=1

so I get
    (v''/v') = -k/m

```
1/a = -k/m
```

integrate both sides

```
ln(a) + d = -kt/m +c

a(t) = Ce^(-kt/m) <--- the general form ?
```

I have spent HOURS trying to figure this out am I on the right path ?

```
At t = 0 v = 0 
mv' = mg

v' = g
```

then after finding the integrals for

```
 1/a = -k/m  

ln(a) + d = -kt/m +c

a(t) = Ce^(-kt/m)
```

which then follows through to be

```
g=ce^(0)

g = c

a(t) = ge^(-kt/m) <-- so this is the specific form for a sky diver who starts at acceleration = 0 ant  = 0?
```

Thanks

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you shouldn't be integrating. Just differentiate your velocity term

$$v'' = - \frac{kv'}{m}$$

and substitute in the equation you have for $v'$.

Comment: $v'' = 1$ only if $a = t+ C$, which it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\dfrac{dv}{dt}=m - \dfrac{kv}{m}$,

You were on the write track, but you wouldn't use $v=at$. That equation is only for constant acceleration, which is not the case here. The more accurate formula is $a= \dfrac{dv}{dt}$

Differentiating both sides:

$\dfrac{d^2v}{dt^2}=- \dfrac{k}{m}\dfrac{dv}{dt}$

And then making the substitution that $a= \dfrac{dv}{dt}$:

$\dfrac{da}{dt}=- \dfrac{k}{m}a$

This would be your differential equation, and thus your answer. Solving it, if you wish, would give you:

$a(t)=a_0 e^{-\frac{k}{m}t}$, where $a_0$ is the initial acceleration at $t=0$.

Initial acceleration would simply be the gravitation constant of Earth, and then as time passes, the acceleration of the sky diver drops to 0 as he/she reaches terminal velocity. This is what this function depicts.